# How to enable PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I have little server in Slicehost and i installed PHP 5.2.10 with PDO disabled. Now i'd like to enable it. Is there a way to enable it without too much fuzz? I'm not a pro admin :P.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Update the php.ini file to point to the shared module

```
extension=pdo.so
```

See the [PDO installation instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php) for more information.